# Filter by fields from joined table when using includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models like this:

`Account` - has 2 columns `account_id` and `account_name`

`MonthForecast` - has 3 columns - `account_id`, `entity` and `report_key`

I have `has_many :month_forecasts` defined in `Account` and `belongs_to :account` defined in `MonthForecast`.

I am using an includes like this:

```
@months = Account.includes(:month_forecasts)
```

How do I apply a filter condition to a field that exists only in `MonthForecast` during the `includes` operation above?

Comment: You mean to retrieve account those have month_forecasts  ?

Comment: @vishal - I know that `@months = Account.includes(:month_forecasts)` would do that for me. My question is, I need to apply some filter condition on `MonthForecast` on a field that exists only in it and NOT in `Account`. How do I apply that filter either before or during the `includes` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the joined table name in `where` like it is shown below (depending on rails version you might also need to include `.references(:month_forecasts)`):

```
Account.includes(:month_forecasts)
       .where(month_forecasts: { field: :value })
```